# Array access in assembly language

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to simply sum up an array in assembly.

```
int main(){
 int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
 int result;

 _asm{
   mov ecx, 5 ;set the counter for 5
   mov eax, 0 ;zero eax
 NXT: add eax, [esi*4+a] ;add array value
      inc esi ;increase esi to read next value
      LOOP NXT ;loop back to next

   mov [result], eax ;mov eax into result

  }

 printf("result: %u",result);
```

Regardless of what the value of the arrays are, it always sums to 2.

I'm trying to run on a Mac.

I'm compiling using:

```
gcc -fasm-blocks -m32 -c sum.cpp
```

and linking with

```
gcc -arch i386 -g -o sum sum.o
```

I've tried various things, but I can't seem to get it to sum the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you aren't initialising `esi` to anything, so it contains some random value at the start of your loop.

Also, since `a` exists at a *non-fixed* location (it is a local variable, after all), you should load the address of `a` into a register first:

```
lea ebx, a
...
add eax, [esi*4+ebx]
```

I suspect your inline assembler is doing the wrong thing with `[esi*4+a]`.

Comment: It is initialized to zero. I've tested this by just performing `mov [result], esi` in the asm statement.

Comment: @millsj, you shouldn't _rely_ on esi being set to 0, you should explicitly enforce it.

Comment: @paxdiablo understandable, I added a line at the start to set it to 0, there is no change on the output however, it still reads 2.

Comment: Adding the `mov ebx, a` line is now causing a bus error. gdb disassemble shows it occurring on the add line: `0x00001ecd <main+109>: add    (%ebx,%esi,4),%eax`. Is there any way to stop the value of a from shifting around?

Comment: Actually, you might need `lea`, I'll update my answer (it all depends on how your assembler interprets memory references). Or, you could make `a` a global variable.

Comment: @GregHewgill `lea` was the key here! thank you, the code is working now. I appreciate the help.